# How do I reply to a review in Firefox Marketplace?

Tags: firefox-os, marketplace

I just received a review of my application in [Firefox Marketplace](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/earth-mapper-hiking-helper).
The user who left a 3* review had trouble with exporting his map in an Android device (it is a map related application).

I just rechecked the application and it seems to be working fine. Now, I want to reply/revert back to the user asking for a little more details to understand why he is having the problem.

Sadly, unlike Play Store I find no link to reply to a review comment in Firefox Marketplace. Can anyone guide me how do I do it?

Comment: I'm afraid this question appears to be off-topic since it's not so related to programming issue, but more to app store service. I suggest to ask Mozilla directly by going to https://support.mozilla.org/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible but an enhancement has been filed for it.  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=994638

Comment: Thanks. So I presume at present as an Application Developer I don't have any choice to get any more information.

Comment: you can probably asks users to to look at possible issues on the Mozilla mailing list, Mozilla support or irc.  You can also send an email to the developer who approved the app.  Hopefully this bug will make some progress soon.

Comment: Well that is the problem. I cannot as the user to do anything, I ahve no way of communicating to them!!
Will wait till it gets some traction.

Or...
is there a way to contribute in marketplace?

Comment: Here is the link for contributing to the marketplace: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Marketplace/Contributing/Apps